# Extract data inside HTML tags in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

I am trying to extra data from inside html tags. I created a function to act as a split_string like in t-sql. Although it doesnt work consistantly and was wondering what others have found. I will try to include a example but it might not work since there is html tags all over it.

```
<div class="sub-sub-head"><b>Overview:</b></div>Establish and maintain an accurate, detailed, and up-to-date inventory of all enterprise assets with the potential to store or process data, to include: end-user devices (including portable and mobile), network devices, non-computing/IoT devices, and servers. Ensure the inventory records the network address (if static), hardware address, machine name, data asset owner, department for each asset, and whether the asset has been approved to connect to the network. For mobile end-user devices, MDM type tools can support this process, where appropriate. This inventory includes assets connected to the infrastructure physically, virtually, remotely, and those within cloud environments. Additionally, it includes assets that are regularly connected to the enterprise’s network infrastructure, even if they are not under control of the enterprise. Review and update the inventory of all enterprise assets bi-annually, or more frequently.<br/><br/>
 
 <div class="sub-sub-head"><b>Action Items:</b></div>1) Maintain a detailed Hardware Asset Inventory.<br/>
 
 <div class="sub-sub-head"><b>Additional Guidance:</b> </div>Asset Type: Devices <br> <br>
 Security Function: Identify
```

Comment: show an example of what you are trying to do

Comment: I finally figured out how to include it in the post without it actually doing the html, this is an example of a single field that I want to separate

Comment: I see three lines; do those represent values of a column in three rows?  or are all the value of a column in a single row?  and show what you mean by separate; specifically what rows/columns to you want a select to return?

Comment: so I tried to include code but it was 2000 characters and didnt fit, I am separating it into 6 fields, type, description which is using <div class="sub-sub-head"><b> as afield set splitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use substring_index to split; for each field you call it twice, once to get the first N fields, and once to get the last field from that:

```
select
    substring_index(substring_index(bar, '<div class="sub-sub-head">', 2), '<div class="sub-sub-head">', -1) overview,
    substring_index(substring_index(bar, '<div class="sub-sub-head">', 3), '<div class="sub-sub-head">', -1) action_items,
    substring_index(substring_index(bar, '<div class="sub-sub-head">', 4), '<div class="sub-sub-head">', -1) guidance
from foo;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=341bc2ed97636b8cffdebfde0a8eafed)

Comment: Thanks that was a great attempt, I actually went the way of using likes and about 100 replaces based on the data. Then made a view out of the answers. All in all there were 4 sets of task/description fields with 1 id field per line. I also created a custom function called split_str to handle the substring_indexes.